# URL rewrite apache

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

my problem today is to rewriting URL with apache on local wamp.

I've a page like:

```
localhost/TEST/index.php
```

I would like this page like:

```
localhost/TEST/index
```

I pass this step with:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index$ /TEST/index.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

The problem is I would like when I type localhost/TEST/index.php the url is redirect to localhost/TEST/index

How can i do that please?

Thx

Comment: Have you tried `RedirectPermanent /TEST/index.php http:/localhost/TEST/index` ?

Comment: If i had RedirectPermanent /TEST/index.php http:/localhost/TEST/index  after my RewriteRule he say The requested URL /TEST/index was not found on this server.

Comment: Because the file doesn't exists… I don't know how to do that. But, would your user really access http:/localhost/TEST/index.php ? If all your links are http:/localhost/TEST/index it should be fine...

Comment: Nope the link is index.php with ?page=XX after!
If i put RewriteRule with R Flag instead of L,QSA,NC, that work put just few time, after several test i can access to index.php without url forwarding

Answer (score 0):

Did you resolve your problem? if not, try this : 
`RewriteRule ^Test/test$ Test/index.php [L]`